# How to prevent str_replace on certain parts of the string? PHP?

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I am using PHP's `str_replace` to replace quotes with their HTML entities. However, I'd like to leave out specific words from being replaced, how would I go about doing this?

```
$c = str_replace("'", '&apos;', $c);
$c = str_replace('"', '&quot;', $c);
```

`$c` is the input posted by the user which will be saved as a string which will look like this:

```
"name": **user input here**,
"city": **user input here**,
"country": **user input here**,
```

I'm trying to ignore the `str_replace` on `"name":, "city":, "country":, etc` so the double quotes should be left as they are. `str_replace` should only be used on the **user inputs**.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Do the replacing on the user input before 'name' or whatever has been added? or split it off first and then re-add your prefixes.

Comment: _"I am using PHP's str_replace to replace quotes with their HTML entities."_ - what the heck for? If this was about XSS, you would use htmlspecialchars. // _"How could I achieve this?"_ - your example data seems to be an attempt at creating a key-value storage ... so do this _right_ from the beginning, and use JSON. Functions to en- and decode it, that take care of all possible edge cases, exist already. So no need to roll your own amateurish solution.

Comment: @pvg Once the user inputs data, a whole fresh string is created so it looks a little something like this - `'"name":' . $input`

Comment: @CBroe Yep, that's the what I'm trying to achieve. But using htmlspecialchars in this case would affect "name", "city" and "country" too. Is there any way around this? The whole string shown above is created through JavaScript and then appended to an input hidden tag (so `"name", "city" and "country"` along with the inputs together in the right places are created as one string to be saved in a file. I guess I could edit the code to pass each input in manually but is there a way to do htmlspecialchars with certain parts left out? Thanks!

Comment: @CBroe Through AJAX, whenever a input is updated it will automatically take every specified div which contains info about an individual. It will grab the name, city and country of every input tag, in order, and "combine" them into one string to 'symbolise' a 2D array. That string will then be written to a file

Comment: An easy way would be to replace the replacement afterwards: `$c = str_replace('&quot;name&quot;', '"name"', $c);`. But it's not reliable in any case.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thank you! I will try this out

Comment: @Osman as I said, do the replacing before you make that string. Whatever manipulation you are doing on the user input, there's no point doing it on something other than the user input and then wondering how you can skip the not-user-input part. Just don't add it before the processing to begin with.

Comment: _"It will grab the name, city and country of every input tag, in order, and "combine" them into one string to 'symbolise' a 2D array."_ - stop trying to "symbolize" stuff - make it a proper array or object data structure  and use the JSON methods. Everything else is rather nonsense.